# Looking for sys.sp_add_ct_history

Tags: sql, sql-server

Context:

I'm investigating a claim that the stored procedure sys.sp_add_ct_history is running and causing some slowness on a particular database after updating to SQL Server 2016 SP3. The only mention from Microsoft documentation just says:

> SQL Server 2016 SP3 ...introduced a new table, dbo.MSchange_tracking_history, and a new stored procedure, sys.sp_add_ct_history, to record the history of change tracking cleanup.

This database is indeed using SQL Server Change Tracking on a number of tables, and dbo.MSchange_tracking_history has records. So far, so good.

The issue:
I cannot find sys.sp_add_ct_history anywhere.

EXEC sys.sp_add_ct_history gives a "Could not find stored procedure" error.

I've also tried querying all_objects:

```
SELECT name FROM sys.all_objects
```

...and I return various sys stored procedures, but not that one.

Anybody up to speed on this stored procedure? Anything weird about it? Is it extra hidden somehow? Are there permissions I should check for? This doesn't add up and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: There was a subsequent hotfix that fixed an issue with that particular proc (https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/kb5007039-fix-you-encounter-error-messages-8114-or-22122-when-performing-change-tracking-cleanup-b102b180-a80c-4b32-90d7-0811108fe7d1) - I'm wondering whether that proc itself was removed.  I don't have comparison environments that I can verify.  What specific SQL version are you running?

Comment: This is on build # 13.0.6419.1 (so, after the hotfix, looks like)